# Import Contact From Yahoo Using Angularjs??Any Sample code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to find any tutorial or resources to import contacts from Yahoo. For example, you are asked to authenticate via Yahoo and then you can select the contacts(emails) to import. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps satellizer is a good option.

https://github.com/sahat/satellizer